# What are the various types of tickets for Empire State Building?

Tags: usa, sightseeing, new-york-city

I will be in New York City this summer and of course I want to go on top of the Empire State Building. But as I discovered, there are several ticket categories (VIP, VIP Express, Standard) with each being more pricy than the other. Which ticket will get me to the Top the fastest?

Comment: If you want a great view of NYC, you might consider *not* climbing the Empire State Building, but instead climbing Rockafeller Center, so you can see the Empire State Building. I have only climbed Rockafeller Center, though, so I cannot offer a comparison of the two.

Comment: How to climb the empire state building. In reasonable time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure where you have found the types of tickets you have listed but the [official site](http://www.esbnyc.com/buy_tickets.asp) lists 4 different ones.

- Main Deck - 86th Floor general admission (lines and all)
- Main Deck Express - 86th Floor and you bypass the general admission line.
- Main Deck + Top Deck - 86th Floor + 102nd Floor observation decks in general admission line
- Main Deck + Top Deck Express - same as above with preferential treatment for the elevators.

You can also get NY City Pass which will get you Main Deck Ticket included in it.

But as @Flimzy pointed in the comment the [Top of the Rock](http://www.topoftherocknyc.com/special-offers/combo-tickets/premier-pass/) is a better observation deck to visit because it doesn't have [fence](https://www.google.com/search?q=empire+state+building+deck+view&client=firefox-a&hs=5yh&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=9wOmUc6GFcrD0AGPs4GQDg&ved=0CF4QsAQ&biw=1225&bih=809) around the deck like the Empire State building.

Comment: I've just got back from a trip to NY, and I did Top of the Rock during daylight, and the Empire State at night.  The combination worked really well as the city is impressive at both times.

Comment: @Phil Personally I'm waiting to see what [Freedom Tower](http://www.wtc.com/about/freedom-tower) would show.  I miss the roof deck of WTC 2. :(

Comment: @Karlson I just looked up the Freedom Tower, I think it will set new standards :)

Comment: @Karlson that does look impressive